# Bootstrap jquery slideDown not sliding

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Navbar do appear but it just do popin and popout i want it to slide down after 100px scrolling down.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
      $(".navbar-fixed-top").slideDown();
  }

  if($(window).scrollTop() < 100){
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").slideUp();
  }

  });
});
```

Wrong method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        jQuery(".navbar-fixed-top").stop().slideDown();
    } else {
        jQuery(".navbar-fixed-top").stop().slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this instead

```
  (function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar").hide();
  $(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.navbar').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.navbar').fadeOut();
      }
    });
  });

});
  }(jQuery));
```

slideDown is having a conflict to my css styling :D thanks!